# Can a mysql trigger be used to block an insert?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I've got a mail queue table, and a email black list table.  Inserts to the mail queue table are made in a zillion (literally, I counted) places throughout the code.  I've been tasked with blocking emails to people on the black list.  Can I make a trigger on the mail queue table that rejects inserts if the address is in the black list table?

Is there possibly a better way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TRIGGERs that cause INSERTs to fail? Possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229765/triggers-that-cause-inserts-to-fail-possible)

Comment: Check the link above in the 'possible dupe' comment. It has exactly what you need - a database "on before insert" trigger that causes the insert to fail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so there's no graceful way to to this?

Comment: @Marc B:  If you stick that link in a comment I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not going to take points for someone else's answer.

Comment: I searched SO for it, didn't come up.  No biggie, thanks for getting me the answer. though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Book '[High Performance MySQL Second Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101718/)':

> Sometimes you can even work around the
>   FOR EACH ROW limitation. Roland Bouman
>   found that ROW_COUNT( ) always reports
>   1 inside a trigger, except for the
>   first row of a BEFORE trigger. You can
>   use this to prevent a trigger’s code
>   from executing for every row affected
>   and run it only once per statement.
>   It’s not the same as a per-statement
>   trigger, but it is a useful technique
>   for emulating a per-statement BEFORE
>   trigger in some cases. This behavior
>   may actually be a bug that will get
>   fixed at some point, so you should use
>   it with care and verify that it still
>   works when you upgrade your server.
>   Here’s a sample of how to use this
>   hack:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fake_statement_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON sometable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE v_row_count INT DEFAULT ROW_COUNT( );
IF v_row_count <> 1 THEN
-- Your code here
END IF;
END;
```