# mySQL Unique constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a simple table with 3 columns .

```
| prefix | phoneNumber | verifiedDate |
------------------------------------------
```

verifiedDate  could hold Null

how can I force this constraint on my database? One row for every UNIQUE prefx & phoneNumber exist **if verifiedDate is not NULL.**

duplication of prefx & phoneNumber are only allowed if there is no row that hold prefx & phoneNumber and verifiedDate is not NULL!

Comment: Would be so easy with other DBMS, but MySQL does not support partial indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know to do this is by using [SQL Triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger).

Here are some good resources for mysql specifically:

- [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)
- [MySQL example](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-update.shtml) half way down the page is the code

Comment: I tried that but i think i have a syntax error

CREATE TRIGGER upd_check AFTER UPDATE ON phonenumbers
 DELETE FROM `phonenumbers` WHERE `prefix`=new.prefix AND `phoneNumber`=new.phoneNumber AND `verifiedDate` IS NULL;

Comment: Updated my answer with new links. It appears that in mySQL you have to say ... ON [TABLE] FOR EACH ROW [trigger stuff]. Otherwise this is fine

Comment: #1442 - Can't update table 'phonenumbers' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: Hrmmm, it appears that you have to resort to some trickery to accomplish this in mySQL ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229765/triggers-that-cause-inserts-to-fail-possible )..and I would suggest using the BEFORE UPDATE so that the update basically fails.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to write a query that returns 'bad data' then in a trigger test that this query is the empty set e.g. something like

```
DECLARE unique_tally INT;
SET unique_tally = 0;  

SELECT COUNT(*) 
  INTO unique_tally
  FROM (
        SELECT prefix, phoneNumber, COUNT(*) AS tally
          FROM SimpleTable
         WHERE verifiedDate IS NOT NULL
         GROUP 
            BY prefix, phoneNumber
       ) AS DT1
 WHERE tally > 1;

IF ( unique_tally > 0 ) THEN
   -- Fail
```