# Trigger issue with syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hi to all im trying to create a trigger for this table:

```
create table Episode(
  title varchar(25) not null,
number int not null,
  length time not null,
  aired date not null,
  serie_name varchar(25),
PRIMARY KEY(title,number),
  FOREIGN KEY (serie_name)REFERENCES Serie(name)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

this is a table of a db that saves some tv series...so the trigger have to check if i m trying to insert a new episode that had benn aired before the precedent one....But i have some problem any solutions?
i tried this:

```
create trigger ControlDataEp
 before insert on Episode
 for each row
begin
if new.aired<(select aired from Episode where title=new.title and number=new.number-1)
    then raise.application_error(-21,'error');
end if;
```

end;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't that much care about returning meaningful error message you can simplify your trigger to one statement

```
CREATE TRIGGER ControlDataEp
BEFORE INSERT ON Episode
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.aired = 
(
  SELECT IF(IFNULL(MAX(aired), 0) < NEW.aired, NEW.aired, NULL)
    FROM Episode 
   WHERE title = NEW.title 
     AND number = NEW.number - 1
);
```

What it does it violates `NOT NULL` constraint on `aired` column.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/591ab/1)** demo. *Uncomment last insert statement*

Now if you **do need** to return a custom error message:

1. You can use `SIGNAL` but only if you on MySql 5.5 and higher
2. Use one the hackish ways (read e.g. [TRIGGERs that cause INSERTs to fail? Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229765/1920232), [Throw an error in a MySQL trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24/1920232))

Comment: Ah ok it s awesome but is the first time that i see a query like this.. after the <NEW.aired,(this part with the ",") what are the new.aired and the NULL for?

Comment: @Skyzzo **[`NEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)** is an alias that allows you to refer to the columns of a row that is being inserted (or updated). `NEW.aired` and `NULL` is the 2nd and 3rd argument of **[`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)** function. It allows to check for condition and if it's true return the value that is being inserted (NEW.aired) and it's false return `NULL` thus violating the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't use a trigger when there's no need to.

You can use

- [INSERT IGNORE ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)
- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)
- [REPLACE ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html)

Please have a look in the respective manual pages I linked for additional information.

To explain, why your solution doesn't work:

```
if new.aired<(select aired
```

Your subquery might return multiple rows. Use `SELECT MAX(aired) ...` instead.

```
... and number=new.number-1)
```

It's a bad idea to rely on code outside the database to make sure, that data in the database is okay.

```
then raise.application_error(-21,'error');
```

`raise.application_error()` is not a MySQL built-in function. You can't call functions from your code in MySQL like this. If you really want to raise an error in MySQL use [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/signal.html)s