# how to show a message if condition is true in mysql 5.0 trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a trigger

```
 DELIMITER $$
  DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_insert_on_emp $$
  CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_on_emp
  BEFORE insert ON empefforts
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE MSG VARCHAR(100);
  IF (NEW.TIMING) > 60
  THEN
    SET MSG='Error: TIMING must be <=60.';
  END IF;
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I want  to show the MSG VARIABLE value on console when the condition is true.
How can I show this value. I am using **mysql 5.0.18** version...

Comment: have you tried `SELECT MSG;` ?

Comment: There is no normal way to do it in MySql ver < 5.5. You can try one of  the hackish ways (read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/229765/1920232, http://stackoverflow.com/q/24/1920232)

Comment: @Stephan Yes I tried but it gives me error:Not allowed to return Resultset from a trigger.

Comment: @MaheshPatidar sorry my bad just now i saw that it was a trigger... in this case the only option is to insert the message in a log table

Comment: @Stephan can't I print on the console ?

Comment: @MaheshPatidar from a trigger i do not think so ... i know you can do this in a stored procedure

Comment: check my answer because i found a way

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research i found that there is a way ... using [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) like:

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: TIMING must be <=60.';
```

**UPDATE:** example of procedure that prints a message:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE show_message()
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Error: TIMING must be <=60.'
END//
```

Comment: SIGNAL not support in mysql 5.0

Comment: I am not so much good in procedure so can you write an example of stored procedure to show the example since I tried using procedure also but not worked at all