# MySql - apply same unique constraint to two different combinations of fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique-constraint

How do I specify unique constraint on **different combinations** of fields? E.g.

```
 id  | Fld1 | Fld2 | Fld3
-------------------------
  1  |   A  |  B   |  C
-------------------------
  2  |   A  |  C   |  D
```

I'd like to make the example above illegal because combination (Fld1, Fld3) in row 1 has same values as combination (Fld1, Fld2) in row 2.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/229447/2298301

Comment: Have you checked the link suggested by @DhruvSaxena? Did you understand the approach? With some creativity you can adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way possible for this except a trigger but performance will be a constraint. You can only have combine unique key but this case will not fullfil.