# Using MySQL 1 to many relationship

Tags: mysql, database-design

I currently don't have any code yet. I understand what a 1 to many joined relationship is I just don't know how to make it work. The idea here is that many carriers can have the product and vice versa. How can I keep track of which carriers has which products if each table has only 1 field to keep the others ID in? Here's the example:

### Table: Carriers

- id
- name
- productID

### Table: Product

- id
- name
- description
- carrierID

Comment: this has nothing to do with PHP. If you're having problems with designing database, go learn database concepts.If you don't know how to write SQL,  read a book about it. If you don't know how to use PHP with database, Google for it!

Comment: You are looking for a many to many relationship. You say it yourself in your description. You need another table to hold the relationships.

Comment: .. and since you try to solve it with 1-to-many it shows that you don't understand that concept

Comment: See this example: You need a 3rd table, often called accosiation table or junction table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812680/many-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 1):

Michael,
Either the carriers table or the product table has one too many bit of information.  With this table structure, you would wind up having to create a carriers line per carrier/product and a product line per product/carrier

One way to think about this is to have three tables:

**Table: Carriers**

- ID
- name

**Table: Product**

- ID
- name
- description

**Table: product_carriers**

- carrier_id
- product_id

With this type of structure, you could get all the information off of the product_carriers table, and the product and carriers table would be unique per product and carriers, eliminating duplicate information and speeding up your queries.

Answer (score 0):

you have a third table, containing carrierid and productid and populate with the relationship

e.g.

```
cid,pid
1,1
1,2
2,1
2,4
```

carrier id 1 is related to product id 1 and 2
carrier id 2 is related to product id 1 and 4

product id 1 is related to carrier id 1 and 2

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully understand what you mean. Could you give a more detailed example? (I'm new to this, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a many-many relationship. Many carriers, each carrying one or more (many) products. To accomplish this, you need a 3rd table to produce the linkages:

```
carrier_products:
    carrier_id (foreign key to carriers) 
    product_id (foreign key to products)
```